# local web server not accessible on Chrome - Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, web, nexus-5

I am trying to access my website (hosted on intranet) for testing on Google Chrome for mobile (using nexus 5) and the website is not accessible (on the same network using Wifi). If I access my website from any other pc on the same network it loads the webpage. I just checked that network connection is working fine and on my mobile i am able to browse any website on internet. I found the same behavior on android. Please guide me if there is any settings in android/chrome to access local server. The address of my webserver is like "http://my-server/webapp"

Comment: Try to disable firewall on your system or post the message you are getting while browsing site

Comment: I just checked by disabling firewall, but it didn't worked. BTW as I have mentioned that the website is accessible from all other pc(s) on the same network.

Comment: What are you seeing on web page from mobile

Comment: Are you running on lollipop?

Comment: yes, its lollipop, I just have a responsive website to test there..

Comment: This seems to be a problem only with Lollipop, rest of the mobile in the same networks can access the website.